# George Orwell 1984. What does this sentence actually mean.?

Tags: novel

"The consequences of every act are included in the act itself".. What does this actually mean??

Comment: So where is the appropriate place to ask?

Comment: I think there's a Literature SE -- try there?

Comment: [Literature.se] are the ones who answer questions about existing works of literature. Run a search there before you ask, it might be that a similar question has already been asked and answered there.

Comment: I checked the help center over on Literature and they do cover these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the punishment should be considered a part of the act itself. If you steal, you don't only steal, you also punish yourself by causing the Party to punish you. It's inseparable from one another, you cannot escape the punishment, therefore the act and the punishment are one and the same thing.

It's supposed to show how much power the Party has over you.

Comment: Please refrain from answering grossly off-topic questions.

Comment: @bruglesco I had an answer and I gave it. I figured the question might get closed, yes, but I am not aware of a rule that says I shouldn't try to be helpful?

Comment: There's no *rule*, per se, but it's generally frowned upon. If people get responses to their off-topic questions, it encourages them to keep asking them. Worst case scenario, the site gets cluttered up with questions like this. I know it's not ideal, but it's a consequence of StackExchange's strict Q&A format.

Comment: In the [help] under the section on [How do I write a good answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) it says `Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...` `...are not about writing, copywriting, publishing or editing as defined in the help center.` Also see [this relevant Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133555/384163) cc @F1Krazy

Comment: Well thanks for considering my frustration, but it was no bother at all. And the meta SE answer also suggests to answer the question if it would be a good question on another SE forum. So I think I'll keep answering the same way as before.

Comment: I am in no way considering your frustration. But thank you for equally not considering mine. Did you actually take steps to try to migrate the question? Since this exchange has limited migration options, I'm not very confident you actually considered the answer to that question without assuming it agreed with you.

Comment: I don't get it. The answer clearly says a) that it's only a personal suggestion and b) to answer questions that would be valid questions on other exchanges. If you now say that the situation is not a valid comparison to begin with - I'm not the one who brought it up. (For what it's worth I did try to migrate the question, and couldn't find the option.) As for your frustration, it's entirely self-inflicted. I don't know what you want me to do about it. I disagree with your assessment of this question anyway, I think a question about e.g. mapmaking software is more off-topic than this is.